# Nutch 2.X Plugin Development Tutorial

Tags: plugins, nutch

I am looking for tutorial that helps me learn the development of plugin for Apache nutch 2.X.

I have searched online but all of them are tutorials about nutch 1.X plugin development. Is the development of plugin for nutch 2.X same as the one for nutch 1.X?

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to find such info, but nothing, everywhere just nothing.  No official documentation, i think guys from Apache nutch project don't know words like "documentation"

Comment: I have switched to nutch 1.X. There is more content available online. But still, you are right, it would be nice if the person in charge of nutch project can provide some documentation.